# Как в python проверить что переменная является int()?

Tags: python, if, int

python

```
def del_gost(l_gost):#функцеи передаtтса list
    rm = input("Як що хтось з гостей не прийшов, вкажіть хто саме(номер за списком або ж за статусом і ім`ям ): ").strip().title()#Вводитса int или str  
    if rm in l_gost:#проверка вхождения в список
        return (l_gost.remove(rm))
    elif type(int(rm)) == type(int()):#вот здесь нужна проверка на то что может преобразоватса в int, если нет то дальше 
        if int(rm) < len(l_gost):
            return (l_gost.pop(int(rm)))
        else:
            print(f'{rm} номера в списку не має!')
            return del_gost(l_gost)
    else:
        print('Вu ввелu не корекні дані. Спробуйtе ще раз.')
        return del_gost(l_gost)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 1
y = 3.14
print(isinstance(x, int))
print(isinstance(y, int))
```

Вывод:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Ну, вообще, вопрос про введенные через input данные, так что isinstance тут не поможет.

Comment: @insolor Да там вообще как-то наверчено. Начиная с того, что я мову не разумею, что там вводится вообще непонятно )

Comment: Там не треба нічого розуміти, крім пайтона. Если выводимый текст проигнорировать, то видно, что идет запрос чего-то через `rm = input(...)`, а потом сравнение `type(int(rm)) == type(int())`. Замена этого сравнения на isinstance особо не поможет.